# Canvas patterned pie chart with array image

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns, canvas, pie-chart

I am trying to make a pie chart made by patterns using some images. But I can't see any images which I am trying to show. What is the problem with the following codes?

```
<html> 
  <body> 
    <canvas width="250" height="250" id="canvas"></canvas> 
     <script>
     var imgArray = new Array();
       imgArray[0] = new Image();
       imgArray[0].src = 'p2.jpg';
       imgArray[1] = new Image();
       imgArray[1].src = 'p3.jpg';
       imgArray[2] = new Image();
       imgArray[2].src = 'p4.jpg';
       imgArray[3] = new Image();
       imgArray[3].src = 'p5.jpg';
       imgArray[4] = new Image();
       imgArray[4].src = 'p6.jpg';  

    //initialize data set 
     var data = [ 100, 68, 20, 30, 100 ]; 

     var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
     var c = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
     //draw background 
     c.fillStyle = "white"; 
     c.fillRect(0,0,500,500); 
     //a list of colors 

     //calculate total of all data 
     var total = 0; 
     for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) { 
         total += data[i]; 
      }

      var prevAngle = 0; 
     for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) { 
     //fraction that this pieslice represents 
     var fraction = data[i]/total;
```

In this step, I dynamically try to put the images into the pie chart, but I think the 'src' usage is wrong.

```
      //calc starting angle 
          var angle = prevAngle + fraction*Math.PI*2; 
          var pat=c.createPattern(imgArray[i].src,"repeat");

     //draw the pie slice 

     //create a path 
      c.beginPath(); 
      c.moveTo(250,250); 
      c.arc(250,250, 100, prevAngle, angle, false); 
      c.lineTo(250,250); 
      c.closePath();
     //fill it
      c.fillStyle = pat; 
      c.fill(); 

     //stroke it 
     c.strokeStyle = "black"; 
     c.stroke(); 

    //update for next time through the loop 
     prevAngle = angle; </script> </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your suspicion.

createPattern takes an image object--not a URL.

```
var pat;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    pat=c.createPattern(img,"repeat");
    // now you can create a path and fill it with `pat`
}
img.src="http://whatever.com/whatever.png";
```

**[ Added image loader code in response to additional question ]**

```
// image loader

var imageURLs=[];  // put the paths to your images here
var imagesOK=0;
var imgArray=[];
imageURLs.push("p2.jpg");
imageURLs.push("p3.jpg");
imageURLs.push("p4.jpg");
imageURLs.push("p5.jpg");
imageURLs.push("p6.jpg");
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgArray.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgArray[] array now holds fully loaded images

    // the imgArray[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]
    // imgArray[0] is p2.jpg
    // imgArray[1] is p3.jpg
    // imgArray[2] is p4.jpg
    // imgArray[3] is p5.jpg
    // imgArray[4] is p6.jpg

    // create your patterns now

}
```

Comment: it didn't work :(. Also I want to put all pictures into pie chart, accordingly. Should I use the `img.src` like that `img.src=imgArray[i].src`?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/rgdCf/  Again...the context.createPattern method takes an image object as its parameter, not a URL (like .src).  So if you want to create multiple patterns for multiple wedges, you would need to preload all the images and then feed them into the multiple patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your help markE. But how can I preload the all images and feed them?

Comment: You're welcome! I have added to my answer with image loader code that will preload all your images and then call the start() function when they are all fully loaded.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: My friend markE, I don't wanna bother you but my codes gives me "image load failed" error! If I put the pattern inside the start(), I will need to use a loop for pie data as in my first code. But in your code, you preload images with the loop. Also, you put the all images into `imageURL`, why would we need any other array `imageArray`. Sorry to bother you again. I am C++ programmer and I am new to these staff.

Comment: Here is a demo showing the image loader.  Hope this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/jSwUY/  Cheers!